# how do I add class of div from other page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to remove class of div id from other page anchor link.

firstPage.html

```
<div class="question show" id="a1">
Sample 1
</div>

<div class="question" id="a2">
Sample 2
</div>
```

list.html

```
$(function () {

             $("a").click(function () {
                 $("#a2").addClass('question show');                
             });


         });
     </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="firstPage.html#a1">Link 1</a>
<a href="firstPage.html#a2">Link 2</a>
</body>
```

I want to add class `addClass('question show')` to that div id which is clicked.

I tried here with `Link1` for `id=a1`

`But I'm failed to set class ('question show') help me to correct my code` 
Please check code here
http://plnkr.co/edit/fzdfjdrRbcWmir5wHcJW?p=preview

Comment: Better you can demonstrate the your code in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co)

Comment: a1 already has that class, try  `$("#a2").addClass('show');` Is that what you mean?? confusing wording..  -also can classes have 2 words?

Comment: @JFit, yes, `class` can contain multiple class names separated by a space

Comment: Your question TITLE says "remove class", but your question says "add class"... which is it?

Comment: Make it **clear** what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Your list.html page has script which is used element(a1) of the firstPage.html page that is not possible.

Comment: Updated question problem is when I clicked on LINK it show add css class to that particular DIV so that DIV gets VISIBLE and show that DIV

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan please check http://plnkr.co/edit/fzdfjdrRbcWmir5wHcJW?p=catalogue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm taking a different approach. I'll not add the function to *list.html*. Let the page *firstPage.html* be called with the value. We will capture the anchor from *firstPage.html*.

Also, since your all divs have the class 'question'; I'm ignoring that class and targeting only 'show' class.

So, load this function with your *firstPage.html*:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var call = $(location).attr('href').split('#');
    var ancr = $.trim(call[1]);
    if(ancr === undefined || ancr == ''){
        // Anchor not set, do nothing
    } else {
        if (!$('#'+ancr).hasClass('show')) {
            $('#'+ancr).addClass('show');
        }
    }
});
```

I also assume you don't have multiple divs with same ID (which generally should not be).

I hope this will do what you need.

Comment: thanks could you please update it in fiddle it will be good help

Comment: Fiddle has its own url and will be tricky handling 2 pages. Have you tried the provided code? What I've suggested is very easy and minor edit to your code. Remove your js function from list.html and add my js function to firstPage.url. Thats all.